# How to use svg image as background image in Circle Avatar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, background

I've tried these line of code but did'nt work for me,

```
CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: Image(image: SvgPicture.asset("assetName")) as ImageProvider,
                backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                radius: 4,
              ),
```

And also tried this

```
backgroundImage: SvgPicture.asset("assetName"),
```

the error I'm facing is
"The argument type 'SvgPicture' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageProvider?'."

Comment: Does using the SvgPicture as a child instead of a backgroundImage work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this (flutter 3, flutter_svg: ^1.1.6)

```
CircleAvatar(
  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
  radius: 4,
  child: SvgPicture.asset("assetName"),
),
```

Answer (score -1):

There are two options:

First:

```
backgroundImage: SvgPicture.asset("assetName") as ImageProvider,
```

Second: use another [packacge](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg_provider) on top of svg_flutter package:

```
import 'package:flutter_svg_provider/flutter_svg_provider.dart';

Image(
  width: 32,
  height: 32,
  image: Svg('assets/my_icon.svg'),
)
```

Comment: you can't set SvgPicture.asset("assetName") as ImageProvider because svg doesn't inheart from ImageProvider